# How would you calculate the Delta-v needed to intersect a target on the ground on a sub-orbital trajectory?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, astrodynamics, rocket-equation

Let's say I have a sub-orbital trajectory, meaning I'm going to crash into the earth at some point within the first orbital period. I know the true anomaly in which I will impact the surface and by reversing kepleriain orbital elements I also know the position vector of my impact. I've also taken into account earth's rotational speed to find my actual position of impact.

I also know my targets position vector and have also calculated the actual position vector of my target accounting for earth's rotation.
Though I want my current impact position to intersect my target's position.
So what I did was convert my impact position and my targets position into latitude and longitude coordinates.

Then I calculated the bearing between them which gave me the direction I should point towards to get my current impact position to intersect with the target's position. Now I Know the heading I should burn towards.

Ignoring aerodynamic effect and earths rotation. How would I calculate the Delta-v needed to change my impact position so that it intersects with the target's position?

Comment: So...you want to build an ICBM.

Comment: This sounds like a fairly involved optimization problem, with questions of "Why didn't you launch to bring your path over the target, instead of spending a lot of delta-V to change the direction of your velocity mid-flight?"

Comment: I am trying to script a boost back burn for a given latitude/longitude coordinate. It is kind of like an ICBM but you actually want your velocity to be slow enough so that you survive re-entry.

Comment: Careful, the answers for a fully ballistic trajectory vs a re-entry and landing burn are a bit different.  You will deviate considerably from the ballistic trajectory once you initiate the re-entry burn.

Comment: Well yes I will deviate quite a lot from my Initial trajectory, since I'm performing the boost back burn some what close to my apoapsis. The problem is trying to calculate the direction I need to be pointing at and by how much velocity to change my trajectory from A to B.

Comment: You seem to be doing and ellipse to another ellipse impulsive transfer. I think there are standard formulae for such a transfer if you know the starting and destination ellipses.

Comment: I have an idea of using a PID controller. So basically I will use a future true anomaly in my sub-orbital trajectory, one that I will arrive at soon since it's more efficient to do burns earlier and I will have enough time to compute my results. Then I convert that chosen true anomaly into a position. Knowing the position, I can pre-simulate a burn, so I don't have to.